# Script for joining all objects which uses the same material

Tags: scripting, materials

i have a scene with a lot of objects and some of them are using the same material. I would need a scipt, which would go through all objects , check if the share a material with some other object and if so,join them into one object (shift+l = select by material ? )

Thanks a lot !
[image]

^ 5 objects are using material, in this case called 2728

Comment: That's not a question, that's a request for cheap labor.

Comment: ... in future it is preferable you demonstrate what you have tried so far. (like your previous q)

Comment: Do you need a script for this? Because this is quite easy to do with just a couple of button presses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Join all objects in scene that have one particular material.**

Test script, finds all objects that have material name starting with  "2"  in their material slots. Changes the `context.selected_objects` list to match and run the `bpy.ops.object.join()` operator.

```
import bpy

context = bpy.context
scene = context.scene
mats = [m.name for m in bpy.data.materials if m.name.startswith("2")]
for mat in mats:
    obs = [o for o in scene.objects
            if o.type == 'MESH'
            and mat in o.material_slots]

    if len(obs) > 1:
        # clear prior selection
        for o in context.selected_objects:
            o.select = False
        for o in obs:
            o.select = True
        scene.objects.active = obs[0]
        bpy.ops.object.join()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ! It works so far but all my materials are named like a "2728, 2892..." and so on. So i tried  :
mat = bpy.data.materials.get("2***") 
but thats not working :/

Comment: Updated for any material with a name starting with "2"  please in future edit your question to clarify.  Not sure why you think * wildcards are going to work.

Comment: Thanks a lot,that works correctly. Sorry i was not more accurate about my question, i will be more precise in feature,thanks again.